# When does the 11th Doctor find a glowing tree in the TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, episode-identification

In an episode, the Doctor finds a ***glowing tree*** in his **TARDIS**.  What episode is this?

Answer (score 13):

That would be [Journey to the Center of the TARDIS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Centre_of_the_TARDIS)

The 'tree' was where the TARDIS basically grew new components as needed.

[image]

Comment: Unless the OP was thinking of [this instead](http://brianofmorbius.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/name_doctor-12.jpg)?

Comment: Maybe; but the fact that it's identified as a tree suggests the Journey to the Center of the TARDIS item.  The timestream LOOKS a little like a tree, but the tree both looks like one and IS one =)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't think this is actually in the TARDIS, as OP stated in his question.

Comment: @j_kubik: you don't think the picture I posted in my comment is in the TARDIS?

Comment: @KHW: indeed, yours is definitely more likely.

Comment: @j_kubik - Although I don't think the image Paul has is what the OP was looking for, it is in fact in the TARDIS.  Just the giant, gone-to-seed, and mostly dead TARDIS.  Specifically, I believe it was in the control room.